# Rails many-to-many existence query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Kind of a ruby-noob active record query question:

```
Magazine
  has_many :subscriptions

User
  has_many :subscriptions

Subscription
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :magazine
```

In a controller, I'd like to efficiently ask if current_user subscribes to a_magazine.  I think it should be something like the following...

```
Subscription.where("user_id = ? and magazine_id = ?", current_user.id, a_magazine.id).count > 0
```

a) looks right? b) is there a more efficient way (assuming indexes on the FKs) c) stylistically, is there a more accepted or concise way?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: B) Assuming indices on the FKs this query should be really efficient (and probably the most efficient)

Comment: Hi @Aldo'xoen'Giambelluca Actually in my `has_many through` association I have such a similar situation, I'm using right now this <% if product.wishlist.where(:customer_id => current_customer.id).any? %> when rendering Products#index view to know which of the listed products are in the logged `Customer` wishlist and highlight them. But my worry is about performance; when products list is big is it a good way to go? Or there's another more efficient query to not to affect performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more concise way to do it involves using the hash method of declaring queries which reads more easily and leaves fewer opportunities for mistakes:

```
Subscription.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :magazine_id => a_magazine.id).any?
```

You can also add `:through` relationships to check based on a user or the magazine accordingly.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :magazines, :through => :subscriptions
end
```

This makes testing for matches really easy:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.magazines.where(:magazine_id => magazine_id).any?
```

Comment: do i want a comma delimiting the hash, or a conjunctive "and"?  though, i guess either way, i should take advantage of the through, and use the other formulation.

Comment: Hi there! I have such a similar situation, I'm using right now this `<% if product.wishlist.where(:customer_id => current_customer.id).any? %>` when rendering `Products#index` view to know which of the listed products are in the logged `Customer` wishlist and highlight them. But my worry is about performance; when products list is *big* is it a good way to go? Or there's another more efficient **query** to not to affect performance?

Comment: That's a classic N+1 query situation. What you probably want to do is preload all the `product_id` values in the wishlist that overlap with the `products` list using some kind of query. A model-level class method that returns IDs is a good place to put this.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a classic has_many :through association to me. See here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Basically your User has_many Magazines through the Subscription and your Magazines also have many Users through Subscriptions. With those associations set up your code should simplify.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your association to a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) relationship. This way you have a Model that's referential through both Models.

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :magazines, :through => :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :magazine
end
```

Now you can check which `Subscriptions` a `User` owns like so...

```
User.find(current_user.id).subscriptions # => Returns a list of Magazine id's
```

And you can check if a `User` has a `Magazine` through a `Subscription` like so...

```
User.find(current_user.id).subscriptions.find_by_magazine_id(1).any?
```

Comment: The last line is not a user, but a subscription. Should be `@subscription` and not `@user`. You can also use `find_by_magazine_id(1)` or `where(:magazine_id => 1)` which is harder to mess up.

Comment: I didn't mean to include an instance variable, thanks for catching that. Also thank you for pointing out the extra methodology! +1